# Symfony how to parse RSS feed on Twig

Tags: php, symfony, rss, twig

For example, in PHP a way to parse RSS feed could be:

```
<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://blog.wordpress_site.com/feed/');

{{ rss }}

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    echo $item->title;
    echo $item->link;
    echo $item->description;
    echo $item->guid;
}
?>
```

How can I have this on Twig?

**UPDATE**: Thanks to the reply I got it. Now it gets this by item but not some fields like image, category or text of the post:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#955 ▼
  +"title": "Website. Description of the website"
  +"link": "http://blog.website.com/liktothepost"
  +"pubDate": "Fri, 17 Feb 2017 07:56:43 +0000"
  +"category": SimpleXMLElement {#1131}
  +"guid": "http://blog.website.com/?p=400"
  +"description": SimpleXMLElement {#953}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create a controller with an action to pass the object to your Twig file that you want to render like so:

```
public function viewRSSAction(Request $request){
    $rss = simplexml_load_file('http://blog.wordpress_site.com/feed/');

    return $this->render('my_rss.html.twig', array(
            'rss' => $rss,
    ));
}
```

Then your `my_rss.html.twig` might look like this:

```
{% for item in rss %}
    {{ item.title }}
    {{ item.link }}
    {{ item.description }}
    {{ item.guid }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks! based on your reply I finally did a Twig function in one extension with your code, thanks! I have updated the issue with another one, please could you help me?

Comment: Can you post a new question for this? It seems like another issue... I'll look at it when I can. Also I don't see `image` or `text` in that dump, so make sure you provide good details of the problem.